# Terraform: How to get a boolean from interpolation?

Tags: terraform

I want to use an interpolated value for the `prevent_destroy` meta-parameter

When I code

```
lifecycle {
   # never destroy the IP address of the production stage,
   prevent_destroy = "${var.stage_name == "global" ? true : false }"
}
```

I get

```
* cannot parse 'prevent_destroy' as bool: strconv.ParseBool: parsing "${var.stage_name == \"global\" ? true : false }": invalid syntax
```

Equivalent error for

```
lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = "${var.stage_name == "global" ? 1 : 0 }"
}
```

When I define a local the definition

```
locals  {
  booltest = "${var.stage_name == "global" ? true : false }"
}
```

seems to go through, but referring to the local

```
lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = "${var.booltest}"
}
```

gives me a

```
* cannot parse 'prevent_destroy' as bool: strconv.ParseBool: parsing "${var.booltest}": invalid syntax
```

(also tried with 0 and 1)

How can this be coded? My version is `Terraform v0.11.10`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately lifecycle attributes do not support interpolation:

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/3116
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/17294

However, using `count` you may work around this. Roughly:

```
resource "aws_instance" "indestructible" {
  count = "${var.prevent_destroy ? "1" : "0"}"
  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = "true"
  }
  ...
}

resource "aws_instance" "destructible" {
  count = "${var.prevent_destroy ? "0" : "1"}"
  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = "false"
  }

  ...
}
```

Personally I would use the same `prevent_destroy` setting between environments and destroy them explicitly when needed.

Comment: Thank you @bkconrad, this seems to work nicely. However, it brings up a follow-up question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53744441/how-to-refer-to-alternate-resources-in-terraform/