# How to refer to alternate resources in Terraform?

Tags: terraform

Terraform (as of today) has the somewhat disturbing limitation, that you cannot create a resource with an interpolated (calcuted) `lifecycle` attribute `prevent_destroy`.

- [Terraform: How to get a boolean from interpolation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53727357/terraform-how-to-get-a-boolean-from-interpolation)
- https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/3116

The work-around is pretty simple to code, just create 2 resources with "alternating" counts. When you have 1 "production" resource which does not allow destroying you have 0 "testing" resources which can be destroyed. Or the other way round. (See the answer to the stackoverflow question linked
above for details.)

However, this brings up a new question. When I want to refer to "the one of the alternate resources that exists for this execution", how do I do that?

In pseudo code something like

```
"${local.production ? "${aws_eip.commander_production.public_ip}" : "${aws_eip.commander_testing.public_ip}" }"
```

This pseudo code cannot work for a couple of reasons:

- `aws_eip.commander_production` is no longer a single resource, it is a list, so you need the `*` syntax
- one of the lists is always empty and Terraform easily complains that it cannot determine the type of an empty list. (I guess because the ternary operator requires that the alternates have the same type)
- when you access into an empty list you will get an error (With C semantics the unused alternate would not be evaluated, but Terraform seems to work differently and I got errors when trying to code this)

To work around those I came up with the following hacky solution:
Extend the lists with a dummy element in the end and then refer to the
first element of the extended list. The code for this is pretty
horrible to type, but it seems to work

```
locals  {
  dummy = [ "foo" ]
}


output "0101: address" {
  value = "${format("Public IP is %s", "${local.production ? "${element("${concat("${aws_eip.commander_production.*.public_ip}", "${local.dummy}")}", 0)}" : "${element("${concat("${aws_eip.commander_testing.*.public_ip}", "${local.dummy}")}", 0)}" }")}"
```

}

**Question:** What is a shorter / more elegant way to code this?

**Note:** I have found one answer myself, but feel welcome to contribute even better ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit shorter code is

```
output "0101: address" {
   value = "${format("Public IP is %s", "${element("${concat("${aws_eip.commander_production.*.public_ip}", "${aws_eip.commander_testing.*.public_ip}")}", 0)}")}"
```

}

In plain text: Concatenate the lists and take the first element of the the result. One list has one element and the other one zero, so the result will be what we want, regardless whether the element is in the first or second list.